# Does database information on uninstall

Tags: android, database, uninstallation

Does the databases of an application get deleted on uninstall and on an update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All files, including databases, stored in internal storage are removed on an uninstall. They are unaffected on an update except in odd cases (e.g., you change your `sharedUserId`).

Comment: If you wanted to delete a database on update, this can be done if you're using SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: However the Clear data function in Settings/Applications/SomeRandomApp (where you can Force Stop and uninstall the app) is greyed out, despite a database being present in the external file system, any ideas?

Comment: @Zainodis: Internal storage != external storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare So much I know ;) a colleague put our database on our application's external storage directory and he says, he can still execute "clear data" on his phone (Galaxy Note/SIII, SDK 14) on mine however (SII, SDK 10) it's greyed out. And I was asking him how the phone knows where our database is, if it's external, however he didn't really know "how" or even "if". P.s. He said starting from API Level 8, upon uninstall even Application files on external storage are cleared (which I can confirm). This also includes our database, but i'd like that clear data to work as well...

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you put your files on some arbitrary place on external storage (SD card), they will not be deleted after you uninstalled your app. If you used getExternalFilesDir() (Android 2.2+) to get the directory to store your files in, they will be deleted when the app is uninstalled. On some early versions of Froyo, there is apparently a bug that deletes the files even on app upgrades, so you might want to watch out for this.